# What is the meaning of “to spite the whole world"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I found that in this text:

> recently wrote on Twitter that he was willing to revise his position
>   towards ISIL and join it “to spite the whole world" if it stopped
>   labeling other jihadists as apostates.

Comment: It's exactly what its component words mean. To deliberately hurt or annoy the entire world. What bit of it are you having trouble with?

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

The verb "spite" means to hate or disrespect or even to show contempt or despise and also to offend, disregard, defy. Lots of definitions there. I think one of these will make you understand the meaning.